# Is it possible to control echo hardware with a raspberry pi

Tags: audio, home-automation

I'm in the process of building some voice-activated features in my Raspberry Pi. I've been looking at off-the-shelf microphones and speakers, and using my Amazon Echo as reference. It has occurred to me that all of the hardware components I'm going to need are available in my Echo, and are the perfect components for the use case at hand. I'm wondering, if I were to dismantle my echo, whether it would even be possible to interface with and use, say, the microphone from the Echo.

Comment: Hi and welcome Gus. Are you asking if you can disassemble your Amazon Echo and repurpose its microphone? Or do you want to somehow control your Amazon Echo from your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hi there, thanks! The former - I'm wondering if I can interact with the hardware directly.

Comment: I believe this should be possible. However, I think this is a question best suited for another Stack Exchange site, like [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).